# conflicting dependency when installing MDT Papyrus - SDK: Runtime, Tools, Documentation and sources (Incubation)

Tags: eclipse

When I try to install "MDT Papyrus - SDK: Runtime, Tools, Documentation and sources (Incubation)" in Eclipse I get the following error:

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: MDT Papyrus - SDK: Runtime, Tools, Documentation and sources (Incubation) 0.8.2.v201202150957 (org.eclipse.papyrus.sdk.feature.group 0.8.2.v201202150957)
  Software currently installed: Eclipse RCP 4.6.2.v20161124-1400 (org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group 4.6.2.v20161124-1400)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    International Components for Unicode for Java (ICU4J) 4.4.2.v20110208 (com.ibm.icu 4.4.2.v20110208)
    International Components for Unicode for Java (ICU4J) 4.4.2.v20110823 (com.ibm.icu 4.4.2.v20110823)
    International Components for Unicode for Java (ICU4J) 56.1.0.v201601250100 (com.ibm.icu 56.1.0.v201601250100)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse 4 Rich Client Platform 1.5.2.v20161122-1740 (org.eclipse.e4.rcp.feature.group 1.5.2.v20161122-1740)
    To: com.ibm.icu [56.1.0.v201601250100]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: MDT Papyrus - Backbone (Incubation) 0.8.2.v201202150957 (org.eclipse.papyrus.backbone.feature.group 0.8.2.v201202150957)
    To: org.eclipse.papyrus.properties [0.8.2.v201202150957]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: MDT Papyrus - Runtime and Tools (Incubation) 0.8.2.v201202150957 (org.eclipse.papyrus.feature.group 0.8.2.v201202150957)
    To: org.eclipse.papyrus.backbone.feature.group [0.8.2.v201202150957]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Papyrus properties runtime (Incubation) 0.8.2.v201202150957 (org.eclipse.papyrus.properties 0.8.2.v201202150957)
    To: bundle com.ibm.icu [4.4.0,5.0.0)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: MDT Papyrus - SDK: Runtime, Tools, Documentation and sources (Incubation) 0.8.2.v201202150957 (org.eclipse.papyrus.sdk.feature.group 0.8.2.v201202150957)
    To: org.eclipse.papyrus.feature.group [0.8.2.v201202150957]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse RCP 4.6.2.v20161124-1400 (org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group 4.6.2.v20161124-1400)
    To: org.eclipse.e4.rcp.feature.group [1.5.2.v20161122-1740]
```

I am new to Eclipse and I have no idea how to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you are trying to install is too old for Eclipse Neon.2 (4.6.2). It wants a version of the `com.ibm.icu` plugin which is at least 4.4 but less that 5.0, Eclipse Neon has version 56 of this plugin!

If this is Eclipse Papyrus you are trying to install look at https://eclipse.org/papyrus/download.html rather than the old MDT site. Or just use 'Help > Install New Software', choose the Neon update site and search for Papyrus.